# Shape changing blobs

Tags: delphi, animation, drawing, morphing

Ok, I'm not quite sure if this is something I can ask here so no need to shoot me down. Just tell me and i'll delete the question :)

I had this idea of making my own clock using a touch screen and program it myself.
While thinking about this I thought of all these different styles to show the current time.

Of all the styles I came up with there was one that I found the most fun which is a clock displaying the time Rorschach style. And no not just a random smudge and guess what time it is but more like Rorschach in watchmen.

He has a mask with inkblots that constantly change shape (really cool if you ask me).
So what I had in mind is inkblots that change shape according to the digit it represents.
When the time changes
`12:49:58 -> 12:49:59` the 2nd second digit will transform from 8 -> 9.

So now back to the original problem:
Before attempting to get this type of clock running I want to try to give a blob a certain shape and make it transform into another shape.
I searched on google but without any luck so I was hoping there was someone here that could point me in the right direction for making a random blob and transform it into another shape in an animation.

For example:
Draw square -> animate to circle

Any tips and tricks are welcome :)

Comment: Animating between shapes is known as "morphing". There are a wide variety of algorithms out there; I'd suggest picking one and implementing it (and asking here if you have trouble, of course :))

Comment: @DavidM Thanks i'll search on that :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the most simpliest animation of digit transformation you could store all posible digits in one image (verticaly) and then only partially show that image in your component. So when you want to do transformation between one digit to another you simply slide the image up and down.

Now if you are using FireMonkey you could create a 3D viewport and inside it create a cylindical object onto which will you render your texture with digits. So now you only rotate the cilinder in order to show the corect digit.

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of transformation the OP means - they want to transform the *shape*.